# \usepackage{xparse} \DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g} What are the g's

Tags: xparse

I found some latex source code that has the following syntax:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\topic{ m m g g g g g}
```

I'm trying to figure out what the four "g" type is for.  Why would it not be better to use "o" types instead?

Comment: I would recommend you to look at [xparse](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/texlive-doc/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.pdf) package

Comment: @Mannie While I agree with the sentiment, why link to an ancient version of the documentation?

Comment: Cheatsheet: https://github.com/rogard/xparse-cheat/blob/master/xparse_tut.pdf

Comment: @schtandard my bad!

Comment: note that g is a deprecated argument type that breaks normal latex syntax rules

Comment: @schtandard :) The recent xparse package documentation http://ctan.asis.ai/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Why don't you just remove `g` from `xparse`?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in section 1.8 of the [`xparse`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) documentation, the `g` argument type is an optional argument given in braces. The same section also explains that it is only provided for backwards compatibility (i.e. so that `xparse` can mimic existing LaTeX syntax) and should be avoided.

So, to answer your second question, it would certainly be better to use `o` type arguments.